# Use PowerShell to determine length of a line in a text file

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I'm new to PowerShell, but I would like to use it, because there isn't a easy way to get the length of a string in Windows batch.

I need to write a piece of code in PowerShell that go through each line in a .txt file and determine the character length of that line. If the character length is over 250 then....etc.

The ....etc part is not important at the moment :)

In Windows batch I would write it like this:

```
FOR /F %%A IN ("C:\TestFile.txt") DO (
    SET LINE=%%A
    If LINE > 250 characters then (        ' This line is made up
    ....etc
    )
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will do what you want:

```
$data = Get-Content "C:\TestFile.txt"
foreach($line in $data)
{
   if ($line.Length -gt 250) {
       Write-Host "A match"
   }
}
```

Comment: `Get-Content "C:\TestFile.txt" | ? { $_.length -gt 250 } | % { Write-Host "a match" }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
:: Not fully tested:
for /f "delims=" %%s in (C:\TestFile.txt) do (
   set "x=%%s" & set /A y+=1
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   for /f "skip=1 delims=:" %%i in ('"(set x&echo()|findstr /o ".*""') do set/a n=%%i-4
   if !n! gtr 250 echo Line !y! Length !n!
   endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for this today and found an elegant solution here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38934/finding-the-longest-line-of-a-document/38936

```
GC "c:\folder\file.txt" | Measure -Property length -Maximum | Select Maximum 
GC "c:\folder\file.txt" | Sort -Property length | Select -last 1
```

Important: credit goes to Pimp Juice IT from the link above, I'm just copy/pasting : )